# What will GitHub do to Pull Requests after filter-branch?

Tags: git, github

We would like to do a `git filter-branch` on all our exiting branches to fix up code style. However, we have a couple of dozen pull requests open in GitHub. Since all the history of the branches will be rewritten what will happen? Also to all the discussion of merged pull requests?

Comment: Why would you use `filter-branch` if all you want to do is to "fix up code style"? Why not fix up the code style in new commits, like you would treat any other change?

Comment: @Chris then you would lose all the authors for git blame, the team could know to go back one more author but it's confusing and painful.

Comment: IMO that's a _much_ smaller challenge than dealing with commit hashes changing. I would advise you to live with the very minor inconvenience of a formatting commit.

Comment: I appreciate what your saying @Chris but my question was not asking for alternate solutions - we have already decided that formatting this way would destroy too much history.

Comment: I understand your question, and I respect that you want an answer to it. I haven't voted to close it or anything similar. However, I have to point out that, contrary to your last comment, my option doesn't damage history at all, while yours does in a major way. Your concern over PRs is just one example of the types of big problems you can expect.